# Excel VBA List Files in Folder with Owner/Author Properties

Tags: vba, excel, properties, filenames

This works, but is painfully slow:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetDetails()
  Dim oShell As Object
  Dim oFile As Object
  Dim oFldr As Object
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim iCol As Integer
  Dim vArray As Variant
  vArray = Array(0, 3, 10, 20)

  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  lRow = 1
      Set oFldr = oShell.Namespace("\\mysite\www\docs\f150\group\IDL\collection\")
      With oFldr
        For iCol = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
          Cells(lRow, iCol + 1) = .getdetailsof(.items, vArray(iCol))
        Next iCol
        For Each oFile In .items
          lRow = lRow + 1
          For iCol = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
          On Error Resume Next
            Cells(lRow, iCol + 1) = .getdetailsof(oFile, vArray(iCol))
          Next iCol
        Next oFile
      End With
End Sub
```

I have the code below working, but I still cant get the Owner/Author or the specific file types.

```
Sub getFiles()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\mysite\www\docs\f150\group\IDL\collection")
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
        With Cells(i + 1, 1)
            Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
                Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Path
        End With
    'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.DateLastModified
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I am trying to get a list of certain files and attributes into an Excel document, but the code keeps causing Excel to crash.
The code below may have some redundancy because I've been fiddling with it all day. Ultimately I would like to get the .pptx and .pdf file names, DateLastModified, and the owner or author

```
Sub ListAllFile()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFolderItem As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim myExt1 As String
    Dim myExt2 As String
        myExt1 = "*.pptx"
        myExt2 = "*.pdf"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add

    'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\mysite\www\docs\f150\group\IDL\collection")
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The current files found in " & objFolder.Name & "are:"

    Set objFile = objFile
    'Loop through the Files collection
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If StrComp(objFile.Name, myExt1) = 1 Or StrComp(objFile.Name, myExt2) = 1 Then
            Dim strFilePath As Object
            Dim arrHeaders(35)
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim objShell As Object
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("\\mysite\www\docs\f150\group\IDL\collection")
            Set objFileName = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)

            For Each objFile In objFolder.Items
                ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
                ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 2).Value = objFile.DateLastModified
                'This returns the "Owner" as the value for every file (not what I want)
                ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 3).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 10)
                'This returns the "Author" as the value for every file (not what I want)
                ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 4).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFile, 20)
                'This returns the actual owner
                ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 5).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 10)
                'This returns the actual author
                ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 6).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 20)
            Next
        End If
     Next
    Columns.AutoFit

    'Clean up
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objFileName = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need `Set objFile = objFile`

Comment: lol indeed I do not; hence my warning of redundancy. Thank you!

Comment: *but the code keeps causing Excel to crash* - it would be more helpful if you tell us the line of code that causes Excel to crash. Have you stepped through line-by-line? Also, perhaps cleaning up the redundancies will help the code process more cleanly. Lastly the variable `strFileName` is **never set nor declared**. Perhaps you meant to `objFile` in it's place in the last two lines before the `Next` statement.

Comment: You are using the variable `objFile` in both `for each` , which are nested

Comment: Also, the variable `objFilename` is not declared and is also set but never used

Comment: `strComp`  does not handle wildcards like `*` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/9s233cfc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: This code works and prints 4 lines and then breaks saying that the method is not supported. It breaks at GetDetailsOf.  `Dim objFolderItem As Object
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
'For Each objFile In objFolder.Items
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 2).Value = objFile.DateLastModified
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 3).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 10)
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 4).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 20)`

Comment: The files are closed however I've noticed that if I open PowerPoint, PowerPoint shows that the files have been opened. I'm not sure why this is, but I suspect it's the reason the latest method is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the second for each loop variable name to objfile1 and made appropriate modifications below it:

```
For Each objfile1 In objFolder.Items
    ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objfile1.Name
    ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 0, 2).Value =    objFile.DateLastModified
```

Note that DateLastModified is a property of objFile while Name belongs to objfile1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the CMD.exe `DIR` command to optimize it a bit, as well as a couple of other tweaks:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim myExt1         As String
Dim myExt2         As String
Dim searchFolder   As Variant
Dim finalArray     As Object
Dim shellObj       As Object

searchFolder = "\\mysite\www\docs\f150\group\IDL\collection"
myExt1 = "*.pptx"
myExt2 = "*.pdf"
Set finalArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set shellObj = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(searchFolder)

For Each file In Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR " & searchFolder & "\" & myExt1 & " /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")
    finalArray.Add CStr(file)
Next

For Each file In Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR " & searchFolder & "\" & myExt2 & " /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")
    finalArray.Add CStr(file)
Next

For Each file In finalArray.ToArray()
    With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = CStr(file)
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = shellObj.GetDetailsOf(CStr(file), 10)
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = shellObj.GetDetailsOf(CStr(file), 20)
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Run time error: 429 "ActiveX component cannot create object" at `For Each file In Filter(Split(CreateObject("CMD /C DIR " & searchFolder & "\" & myExt1 & " /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")`

Comment: Progress, it started to run but errored out at `Offset(0, 1).Value = shellObj.GetDetailsOf(CStr(file), 10)` with "Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: I'm getting that too - when I debug is says that `shellObj` is nothing but I've assigned then namespace the same way your original code did.... let me have a play.

Comment: @MacroMan you need to declare `searchFolder` as `Variant`, not `String`.

Comment: @Rory good spot! was looking at the `.Exec()` methods so didn't think there was anything wrong with it but of course, `Shell.Namespace()` requires a variant... edited!

Comment: Getting there, this time it executed fully, but the `.Offset(0, 1).Value = shellObj.GetDetailsOf(CStr(file), 10)
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = shellObj.GetDetailsOf(CStr(file), 20)` printed "Owner" & "Author" for each file rather than the actual Owner/Author

Comment: I don't know where `strFileName` comes from in your original code so I can't replicate that in my answer

Comment: I dont think the source is the issue. This code from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx get the specific user info.
`Dim arrHeaders(35)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\Scripts")
For i = 0 to 34
 arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
Next
For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
 For i = 0 to 34
 Wscript.Echo i & vbtab & arrHeaders(i) _
 & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
 Next
Next`

Comment: GetDetailsOf() requires a objFolderItem object

Comment: @Adavid02 yeah we were discussing it [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30568791#30568791) for a while. Bit of a quirk with the `Shell.Application` namespace when late binding is used.